# pass javascript variable value to c++ variable

Tags: javascript, html, c++, g++

I'm using `g++` to edit an `html` webpage, so how do I pass a `javaScript` variable value to `c++` variable by using a `javaScript` function? e.g.

```
function convert(val){//conversion
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you. g++ is a C++ compiler, not a webpage editor.

Comment: The system is called freelss http://www.freelss.org/ , using webpage as UIR

Answer (score 0):

g++ is a compiler. It can't edit websites.

But if you manage to pass a variable from JavaScript to C++, you need to validate the content of the variable in C++, not in JavaScript. This is because JavaScript treats variables differently than C++ compilers.